# I want to access the products with total amount

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent-relationship

I have 2 tables. One is product(id, name). another is In(id, amount, products_id).
I am trying to get product name with total amount.
Example:
Aerobat-34
God of war-3
Rs537-15

I Joined the tables. Now output is

```
[{"name":"Aerobat","amount":"10"},{"name":"Aerobat","amount":null},{"name":"Aerobat","amount":null},{"name":"Aerobat","amount":null},{"name":"Aerobat","amount":"2"},{"name":"Aerobat","amount":"56"},{"name":"Aerobat","amount":"56"},{"name":"god of war","amount":"7"},{"name":"god of war","amount":"23"},{"name":"Rs537","amount":null},{"name":"Rs537","amount":null},{"name":"Rs537","amount":null}]
```

```
public function index()
    {
        $product = DB::table('Products')
            ->join('ins', 'products.id', '=', 'ins.products_id')
            ->select('Products.name', 'ins.amount')
            ->get();
        echo $product;
    }
```

How to find the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

you could get it like this

```
    public function index()
    {
        $product = DB::table('Products')
            ->join('ins', 'products.id', '=', 'ins.products_id')
            ->select('Products.name', 'ins.amount',DB::raw('sum(ins.amount) as total'))
            ->get();
        echo $product;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function index()
{
    $product = DB::table('products')
        ->join('ins', 'products.id', '=', 'ins.products_id')
        ->select('products.name', DB::raw('sum(ins.amount) as total_amount'))
        ->groupBy('ins.products_id')
        ->get();

    echo $product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use Model relations
first, create a function in the Product model that is called ins()

```
public function ins()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Ins', 'product_id');
}
```

and also you can declare a virtual column for product that executes the total amount of this product.
Notice, you should set name with "get" as prefix and "Attribute" as postfix

```
public function getTotalAmountAttribute()
{
    $totalAmount=0;
    foreach($this->ins as $item){
         $totalAmount+=$item->amount??0
    }
    return $totalAmount;
}
```

and finally, you can use both fields like name & total amount